# Python if...in.. statement. Check for vowel in word

Tags: python, list, if-statement, user-input, in-function

I'm trying to check if the user input contains a vowel or not. However, I've only found how to check for one vowel at a time, but  not all.

```
vowel = ("a")

word = input("type a word: ")

if vowel in word:
 print (f"There is the vowel {vowel} in your word")
else:
 print ("There is no vowel in your word")
```

This seems to work but I get a error if I try to make the vowel variable into a list. ["a","e","i","o","u"]

any ideas how to check for e i o u at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

If you do not need to know which vowels are present, you can use `any` as follows.

```
vowels = ("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")

word = input("type a word: ")

if any(v in word for v in vowels):
    print("There is at least one vowel in your word.")
else:
    print("There is no vowel in your word.")
```

Comment: @MladenMilosavljevic There is no nested loop in my answer.

Comment: You are passing additional iterable in any() as a solution for a person who started with python and is clueless about basic looping.  Do you really think that is good approach?

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep track is also to have an `existence` list that keeps all vowels that exist in a word.

```
existence = []
vowels = ["a","e","i","o","u"]
test_word = "hello" # You can change this to receive input from user

for char in  test_word:
    if char in vowels:
        existence.append(char)
if existence and len(existence) > 0:
    for char in existence:
        print(f"These vowels exist in your input {test_word} - {char}")
else:
     print(f"There are no vowels existing in your input {test_word}")
```

Output:

```
These vowels exist in your input hello - e
These vowels exist in your input hello - o
```

Comment: I find this code a bit excessive for this task. for one, you pick every letter in the search string (N), instead of picking every vowel (5). in the word `hello`, you'd check twice if `l` is among the vowels. it'd be less work to iterate over the vowels and check if each is in the search string. -- further, the condition `existence and len(existence) > 0` is redundant, since you initialized it to be a list already. either side of the `and` suffices here.

Comment: Thanks for the input and suggestions for improvement :). Ideally, I could have returned True from `if char in vowels:` when a vowel is present. However, by looking at the code of the OP I thought there is a need to also know which all vowels could be present within the word, hence the approach. I agree on the second part of the comment fully.

Comment: `for vowel in vowels: if vowel in word: print(vowel, "in word")` (the "simple" variant) -- `found = [vowel for vowel in vowels if vowel in word]; if found: print("found vowels:", found); else: print("no vowels found")` (the "complex" variant) -- that'd also elucidate which vowels are contained, while swapping what letter is looked up in what string.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression can tell you not only if there's a vowel in a string, but which vowels and their order.

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('[aeiou]', 'hello')
['e', 'o']
```

Answer (score 0):

I can solve your problem.
Here is the code:

```
vowels = {'a','e','i','o','u'}

word = input("Enter a word: ")

for vowel in word:

  if vowel in vowels:
    print(vowel,"is a vowel")
```

Comment: You need to format your code properly. Also, code only answers are generally discouraged. Answers should contain an explanation of the problem or solution.

Answer (score 0):

I feel that if you want to use only if statements, then you can only choose one of the vowels but if you wish to use the for and if statements, it can go through with the whole vowels

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

you have to iterate over the list.

```
vowels =  ["a","e","i","o","u"]

word = input("type a word: ")

for vowel in vowels:
  if vowel in word:
     print (f"There is the vowel {vowel} in your word")
  else:
     print ("There is no vowel in your word")
```

iteration is the proces where you go through each item in a list.

for example.

```
list_a = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]

for item in list_a:
  print(item)

#output will be a b c
```

since other user complained in a comment. If you want to stop the loop after vowel found, you should add break statment

```
vowels =  ["a","e","i","o","u"]

word = input("type a word: ")

for vowel in vowels:
  if vowel in word:
     print (f"There is the vowel {vowel} in your word")
     break
  else:
     print ("There is no vowel in your word")
```

Comment: This will print ”There is no vowel in your word” for each vowel that isn’t inside of the word.

Comment: And that is a problem.. why?

Comment: Because that isn’t true in word ”hello”. It will, for each vowel that isn’t inside of that word print that there are NO VOWELS inside of that word, and tell you two times that there is a vowel inside of that word.

Comment: It seems like a bad user experience if the user is repeatedly told: `"There is no vowel in your word"` for each vowel not included.

Comment: Your update is worse, due to it only working if the there is an ”a” in the word, otherwise it will just end the loop too early…

Comment: Are we solving important tasks here or helping a guy with who is in process of learning? I added break statement anyway, just to make you happy.  I was thinking about leaving that for him to find out on his own.

Comment: Dude, who cares, what he is interested is looping over the list. Not perfect soluton for important question of vowel finder function... jesus chist....

Comment: Your time would be better spent finding and fixing your bug than yelling at the internet.

Comment: Life is short, so keep arguing about strangers on the internet as much as possible. :D